# Changing folder permissions to enable PHP to create a file

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php, xampp

This question is quite similar to this one : [Apache not allowing PHP to create file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622426/apache-not-allowing-php-to-create-file)

However, the difference is that I'm running Apache under a XAMPP setup.

PHP looks like this :

```
file_put_contents('image.png', base64_decode("iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA…lb6PwMAAAAASUVORK5CYII="));
```

Here the warning message when setting error reporting to `E_ALL`:

```
Warning : file_put_contents(image.png): failed to open stream: No permission in /opt/lampp/htdocs/contentdb/index.php on line 215
```

(translated it, was in german originally)

What I tried to solve it, according to the accepted answer, and what had already worked in a "normal" Apache setup :

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data "/opt/lampp" -R
# I also tried chown with <myUserName>:<myUserName>, but it didn't work either
```

EDIT : After searching a bit, I found the file `properties.ini`. It contains what I need.

```
[General]
installdir=/opt/lampp
base_stack_name=XAMPP
base_stack_key=
base_stack_version=7.2.7-0
base_stack_platform=linux-x64
base_stack_service=
require_root_privileges=1
[Apache] <- THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
apache_server_port=80
apache_user=daemon
apache_group=daemon
apache_server_ssl_port=443
apache_root_directory=/opt/lampp
apache_htdocs_directory=/opt/lampp/htdocs
apache_domainname=127.0.0.1
apache_configuration_directory=/opt/lampp/apache2/conf
[MySQL]
mysql_port=3306
mysql_host=localhost
mysql_root_directory=/opt/lampp/
mysql_binary_directory=/opt/lampp/bin
mysql_data_directory=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/
mysql_configuration_directory=/opt/lampp/etc
mysql_arguments=-u root -S "/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock"
mysql_socket=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
[PHP]
php_binary_directory=/opt/lampp/bin
php_configuration_directory=/opt/lampp/etc
php_extensions_directory=/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718
```

Next thing to try will be chown with `daemon:daemon`.

But still, the error message keeps appearing, and the file isn't there yet, too.

**Any help is greatly appreciated.**

EDIT : Problem solved, see answer below.

Comment: Please proof you are using www-data as user and as group ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, whats wrong about that ? When I change file ownership to me, I also use <myUserName>:<myUserName>.

Comment: If your xampp is not using www-data what you do is wrong ;-) You need to check your settings on user and group you are supposed to use. It could also be "apache2"  or something you set up yourself ;-)

Comment: I did not set any users up myself, do you know the default XAMPP username ? BTW, how would I check that settings ?

Comment: I know nothing about xampp. I always use our native lampp stack; far more easier cuz it follows the standards ;-)  But is there a my.cnf or php.ini inside /opt/lampp? That would be the 1st things to check

Comment: Have you  looked at [FAQ](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html) for xampp? And are you in that group that owns XAMPP?

Comment: @Rinzwind : No, those files don't exist.

Comment: Please see this article: https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/ubuntu-linux-tutorials/how-to-fix-permission-of-htdocs-folder-in-ubuntu-linux.html

Comment: Edit : Problem solved by making chown with daemon:daemon. Thanks a lot for your efforts :)

Answer (score 1):

After looking up the `properties.ini` file, I found out that my Xampp Apache User was called daemon : `apache_user=daemon
apache_group=daemon`

Therefore, this :

```
sudo chown daemon:daemon -R
```

did the trick !